# How to resize the notification area (width)?

Tags: notifications, customization

On my Tablet¹, notifications seem to have a fixed width – even when in landscape mode. That looks like in the following "borrowed" screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is especially annoying as some notifications are not expandable – so their messages become meaningless. Example: "Action failed. There is a problem with f" – yeah, a f..reaking problem. One doesn't always have the possibility to cross-check them with logcat, as for one the ring buffer might already have been "run over" until one sees the notification, and for the other there isn't always a corresponding entry which one can easily identify.

---

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to resize the notification box? Solutions requiring root or even XPosed are acceptable.

---

¹ <sub>Lenovo Tab3-7 Essential, running Android Lollipop 5.0.1</sub>

Comment: Note: A work-around for me was using the XPosed module [Always Expandable Notifications](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.alwaysexpandablenotifications), which "wrapped" the notification correctly so the full text became readable. As written, I consider that rather a work-around, and still prefer the width to be adjusted.